# What is the broadcast order for the Darkwing Duck episodes on Disney+?

Tags: darkwing-duck

It appears that Darkwing Duck on Disney+ (at least in Belgium) is not in the same order as it was originally broadcast. What's the order to watch the Disney+ episodes in if I want to watch them in broadcast order?

---

Update from 2022-03-25: I have been talking to Tad Stones on Twitter, the creator of the Darkwing Duck animated series in relation to this question (discussion can be found at https://twitter.com/realnzall/status/1507101691187015691), and it appears neither the original broadcast order nor the Disney+ order are the optimal watch order as envisioned by the animation team. Because of this, I have rewritten the question to focus on how to transpose the Disney+ order to the original broadcast order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wanted to answer this question myself as a sort of personal note that might help others as well. Note that it doesn't really matter what order these episodes are viewed in, because Darkwing Duck is like Silver Age comics, where there is a general setting and a loose cast of heroes and villains, but there is not really any transferrable knowledge from earlier episodes that the viewer should be aware of.

1. You don't start with episode 1 on Disney+. You actually start with episodes 29 and 30, which are the two-part pilot numbered 1 and 2 officially.
2. episodes 1 through 28 are episodes 3 through 30 on the official numbering.
3. Disney+ episodes 31 through 65 are numbered the same officially.
4. Disney+ includes the official season 2 as the last 13 episodes of season 1. These are completely out of order:

- Episode 1 of season 2 is episode 70 on D+;
- Episode 2 is episode 72;
- Episode 3 is episode 66;
- Episode 4 is episode 67;
- Episode 5 is episode 75;
- Episode 6 is episode 69;
- Episode 7 is episode 71;
- Episode 8 is episode 73;
- Episode 9 is episode 68;
- Episode 10 is episode 76;
- Episode 11 is episode 77;
- Episode 12 is episode 78;
- Episode 13 is episode 74.

5. Season 2 on Disney+ matches season 3 of the official count, in the following similarly disjointed order:

- Episode 1 of season 3 is episode 4 of season 2 on D+;
- Episode 2 is episode 5;
- Episode 3 is episode 3;
- Episode 4 is episode 2;
- Episode 5 is episode 1;
- Episode 6 is episode 10;
- Episode 7 is episode 8;
- Episode 8 is episode 9 (Absent on Disney+ because it is banned);
- Episode 9 is episode 11;
- Episode 10 is episode 6;
- Episode 11 is episode 7;
- Episode 12 is episode 13;
- Episode 13 is episode 12.

Comment: On Disney+ I see s1e1=Beauty and the Beet, s1e2=Getting Antsy, s1e29=Darkly Dawns the Duck - Part 1, s1e30=Part 2.  So, is Darkly Dawns the Duck Parts 1 & 2 the original pilot?  If so, then you're suggesting watching s1e29+30 first and then going back to s1e1-65 (skipping s1e29,30), followed by s1e70,72,66,67,75,69,71,73,68,76,77,78,74 (all on D+).  And then on to D+ s2.  Right?

Comment: @jrw32982Yeah, DDtD is the original pilot. If you want to watch the episodes in the original broadcast order, then the above order is the right one.

Comment: @Nzall, The "broadcast order" (or syndication order) and "what's the correct order to watch" is not the same. Maybe you should rephrase your question, then, if this was what you were looking for. In your suggested order, the big problem exists, that certain episodes feature characters, that weren't introduced yet. Most prominently 'Just Us Justice Ducks' Part 1 & 2, where Liquidator, Stegmutt and Morgana appear and their introducing episodes are later in this order.

Comment: @d4zed after talking to Tad Stones, the creator of Darkwing Duck, I have found that you're correct in that the broadcast order has been subject to executive meddling from ABC and does not reflect the artistic vision for the show. Because of that I have refocused the question towards the broadcast order part.